# Exclude views from mysql database dump

Tags: view, phpmyadmin, export, mysql

Is there any way to exclude **views** from mysql dump export?

I tried `--ignore-table` command. But this command recommand the parameters of table which i want to exclude.

I have 30 views in my database.

**Is there any simple way to export only table (not views)?**

Thanks

Comment: I use SQLyog from www.webyog.com for this. You can select what table objects you would need like views,sp,triggers or events.. you can include or exclude with the dump

Comment: The free version is available here: https://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/wiki/Downloads

Comment: @SathishD  Thanks, Let me try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658204/backing-up-views-with-mysql-dump), you should be able to pipe the table objects to mysqldump like:

```
mysql -u username INFORMATION_SCHEMA
  --skip-column-names --batch
  -e "select table_name from tables where table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
      and table_schema = 'database'"
  | xargs mysqldump -u username database
  > tables.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

Making it an answer from comment:-)

I use [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com) from for this. You can select what table objects you would need like views,sp,triggers or events.. you can include or exclude with the dump.

The free version is available here: https://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/wiki/Downloads

Comment: SQLyog runs on wine in ubuntu. They do not have a native linux version. Even i have used it in fedora with wine.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add another -p for the mysqldump command. This is what I ended up with:

```
mysql -u root -p INFORMATION_SCHEMA 
--skip-column-names --batch 
-e "select table_name from tables where table_type = 'BASE_TABLE' 
  and table_schema = 'my_database_name'" 
| xargs mysqldump -u root -p --opt --compress my_database_name 
| gzip -9 -c > my_database_name-tables.sql.gz
```

also optimises and compresses the dump + creates a gzip.