# How to save views in MariaDB/MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I need to port my MariaDB to another computer. I regularly use mysqldump to save the structure and tables, so it's not a big deal. But mysqldump does not save the views - or rather the SQL statements behind the views.

How can I save and reload the SQL views?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Backing Up Views with Mysql Dump](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658204/backing-up-views-with-mysql-dump)

Comment: Use `--opt` option while making the dump