# SHOW CREATE VIEW for all views in MySQL

Tags: mysql, view

Is there a way to show all `show create view` for all views at the same time?

I've hundreds of views, and it would be great if there was a built-in function in MySQL to do this

Comment: Note that searches against views in MySQL cannot utilise underlying indexes, rendering their usefulness questionable,

Answer (score 1):

`information_schema` db is your friend. This will show you all the views.

```
SELECT 
   TABLE_SCHEMA,
   TABLE_NAME,
   TABLE_TYPE
FROM 
    information_schema.tables
WHERE 
    table_type = 'VIEW'
```

If you need to see full view definitions you can use this solution - [Backing Up Views with Mysql Dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658204/backing-up-views-with-mysql-dump)

information_schema docs - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-introduction.html